# Why is this Javascript syntax illegal?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, syntax-error

Both Chrome and Safari report this is illegal.  They report "unexpected token 'this'" pointing at the 'this.b'.  Here is the minimum code needed to show the problem:

```
function x(){ this.a = function() {} this.b = function() {}  }
```

It only happens if the two declarations are on the same line.  Any ideas?  Looks legal to me.
It's annoying because this is what comes out of a Javascript minifier.

Comment: There should be a `;` between `{}` and `this.b`. What minifier are you using?

Comment: That's why. Use a semicolon. I doubt your minifier is any good if it's not removing superfluous whitespace, though.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript will automatically insert semi-colons on new lines. What is missing here are the original semi-colons to delimit the end of your statement.

Insert semicolons after your closing braces like proper JS and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no semi-colon terminating the first statement inside the function `x`.

Semi-colon insertion only works at new lines.

```
// Valid but nasty
this.a = function() {}
this.b = function() {}

// Valid
this.a = function() {};
this.b = function() {};

// Valid
this.a = function() {}; this.b = function() {};
```